# problem with logic of area of circle proof

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, proof-writing, circles

I tried proving the formula for area of circle, what I did was talk a circle of *r* radius and find the area under the curve that is $\int_{0}^{r}\int_{0}^{r}  \sqrt{x^2+y^2} dxdy$ and then converting it to polar coordinate and solving it, which will give $\frac{1}{4}^{th}$ of the total area, why is this approach wrong?

Comment: I think the approach is correct

Comment: @vidyarthi But when we change to polar coordinated the equation changes to $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{r}   r^2drd\theta$ but the real equation should be $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{r}   rdrd\theta$

Comment: Can you Explain more detail in why you choose $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ to integrate and how do you find your boundary?
you might find the reason after thinking these.

Comment: @KinshukDua thanks to Ching-Ting Wu, the integral should be $4\int_0^r\int_0^{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}dx dy$

Comment: @vidyarthi why? isn't the equation of the circle $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ so why are we integrating the constant 1 function?

Comment: Because th equation $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$  is Exactly your boundary.
in other words, your boundary of x changes as your y changes.
if you pick both $0\to r$ as your boundary, it includes (r,r), which is outside your circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, the mistake lies in your thinking that integrating $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ over the surface gives you the area, which is wrong. Your integral gives one-fourth of volume of the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2$ in the 3d euclidean octant with height $r\sqrt{2}$. The right integral is $4\int_0^r\int_0^{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}} dx dy$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use polar coordinate, consider$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{r} r drd\theta$$
which is also the $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{r}  \sqrt{x^2+y^2} drd\theta$$ you wanted to integrate. Just the boundaries wrong.